# vba serverXMLHTTP and Request Header Referer

Tags: vba, http-referer, serverxmlhttp

I'm using serverXMLHTTP in vba with Access 2007 to navigate in a URL. I need to set the Referer header in request to the app work correcly becouse the server needs the Referer header. But when a I set the Referer header in serverXMLHTTP, it don´t go into request. Why ?

Example:

```
Dim XMLHTTP As Object
   Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHttp")

   XMLHTTP.Open "GET", "http://X.X.X.X/headers.php", False
   XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Referer", "http://www.example.com/"  'in case the server cares
   XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "TestHeader", "test" 
   XMLHTTP.send ""

    'wait for response
    If XMLHTTP.ReadyState <> 4 Then
      XMLHTTP.waitForResponse 120
    End If

    MsgBox XMLHTTP.responseText
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
```

Headers in request:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: pt-br
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)
TestHeader: test
Host: X.X.X.X
```

TestHeader is ok.... but Referer not.

Can you help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft does not let you set REFERER, as it's considered a security risk that allows spoofing.